# organising frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I think there's something fundamental I don't understand about tkinter but having read loads of tutorials and other answers, I still don't get it. I'm trying to organise a simple GUI. It should have a left hand pane with a game board (the game is othello) which has active buttons (I've left out the action function as that works ok), then a right hand pane which has 3 panes, top to bottom: one with radio buttons to toggle between 1 or 2 player, one with the current score, and one with a game evaluation. For now these latter 2 are just lines of text.

I thought I could set up a grid structure in a parent frame, then have 4 frames inside that grid, and then widgets inside them. Here's the code (you can ignore Board class unless you want to run it: the bit I'm struggling with is in Master)

```
from tkinter import *
from collections import defaultdict
from PIL import Image as PIL_Image, ImageTk

class Master:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = Board()
        self.display = Tk()
        self.f = Frame(self.display, width=1050, height=700)
        self.f.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=8, columnspan=8)
        self.frame2 = Frame(self.f)
        self.frame2.grid(row=0, column=8, rowspan=4, columnspan=4)
        self.frame3 = Frame(self.f)
        self.frame3.grid(row=4, column=8, rowspan=2, columnspan=4)
        self.frame4 = Frame(self.f)
        self.frame4.grid(row=6, column=8, rowspan=2, columnspan=4)
        self.text1 = Text(self.frame3)
        self.text1.pack()
        self.text2 = Text(self.frame4)
        self.text2.pack()
        self.square = defaultdict(Button)
        self.images = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL_Image.open(f)) for f in ['white.png', 'empty.png', 'black.png']]
        modes = [('{} vs {}'.format(i,j), (i, j)) for i in ['human','computer'] 
        for j in ['human', 'computer']]
            v = StringVar()
            v.set(modes[0][1])
        for text, mode in modes:
            b = Radiobutton(self.frame2, text=text, variable=v, value=mode, command=lambda mode=mode: self.cp_set(mode))
            b.pack(anchor=W)
        self.text1.insert(END, 'score')
        self.text2.insert(END, 'evaluation')
        self.draw_board()
        self.display.mainloop()

    def draw_board(self):
        for i, j in [(x,y) for x in range(8) for y in range(8)]:
            self.square[i,j] = Button(self.f, command=lambda i=i, j=j: self.press(i,j), image=self.images[1 + self.board.square[i,j]])
            self.square[i,j].image = 1 + self.board.square[i,j]
            self.square[i,j].grid(column=i, row=j)

    def cp_set(self, m):
        self.pb, self.pw = m
        return

    def press(self, a, b):
        # make it do something
        return
class Board:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        if parent:
            self.square = parent.square.copy()
            self.black_next = not parent.black_next
            self.game_over = parent.game_over
        else:
            self.square = defaultdict(int)
            for square in [(x,y) for x in range(8) for y in range(8)]:
                self.square[square] = 0
            for square in [(3,3), (4,4)]:
                self.square[square] = 1
            for square in [(3,4), (4,3)]:
                self.square[square] = -1
            self.black_next = True
            self.game_over = False
```

This gives a picture in which the top 4 rows of the game board line up with the radiobuttons but the bottom 4 rows get split up, with both text lines sitting in rows of their own, not opposite a row of the game board.

Seeing that this didn't work, I read something about the problem being grid not preserving column and rows between parent and child frames, so I tried a different approach in which the parent frame splits into 2 columns, and then the child frame sits underneath that with its own row/column definitions. But that didn't work either:

```
self.board = Board()
self.display = Tk()
self.f = Frame(self.display, width=1050, height=700)
self.f.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=2)
self.frame1 = Frame(self.f, width=700, height=700)
self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=8, columnspan=8)
self.f2 = Frame(self.f)
self.f2.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, columnspan=1)
self.frame2 = Frame(self.f2, width=350, height=350)
self.frame2.grid(row=0, column=0)
self.frame3 = Frame(self.f2, width=350, height=350)
self.frame3.grid(row=1, column=0)
self.text1 = Text(self.frame2)
self.text1.pack()
self.text2 = Text(self.frame3)
self.text2.pack()

# in this version, Radiobuttons are children of self.frame2,
# and Buttons in draw_board() are children of self.frame1
```

I really liked this second version until I saw the results in which the board has disappeared altogether. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from collections import defaultdict
from PIL import Image as PIL_Image, ImageTk

class Master:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = Board()
        self.display = Tk()

        self.left = Frame(self.display)
        self.left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="new")

        self.right = Frame(self.display)
        self.right.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.right_top = Frame(self.right)
        self.right_top.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsw")

        self.right_mid = Frame(self.right)
        self.right_mid.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.right_bottom = Frame(self.right)
        self.right_bottom.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.text1 = Text(self.right_mid)
        self.text1.pack()
        self.text2 = Text(self.right_bottom)
        self.text2.pack()
        self.square = defaultdict(Button)
        self.images = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL_Image.open(f)) for f in ['white.png', 'empty.png', 'black.png']]
        modes = [('{} vs {}'.format(i,j), (i, j)) for i in ['human','computer'] for j in ['human', 'computer']]
        v = StringVar()
        v.set(modes[0][1])
        for text, mode in modes:
            b = Radiobutton(self.right_top, text=text, variable=v, value=mode, command=lambda mode=mode: self.cp_set(mode))
            b.pack(anchor=W)
        self.text1.insert(END, 'score')
        self.text2.insert(END, 'evaluation')
        self.draw_board()
        self.display.mainloop()

    def draw_board(self):
        for i, j in [(x,y) for x in range(8) for y in range(8)]:
            self.square[i,j] = Button(self.left, command=lambda i=i, j=j: self.press(i,j), image=self.images[1 + self.board.square[i,j]])
            self.square[i,j].image = 1 + self.board.square[i,j]
            self.square[i,j].grid(column=i, row=j)
```

The layout of the frames will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you that's almost perfect. It leaves some blank space at the bottom (which I'm going to try to fix before I ask again!). But one follow-up: what does sticky='new' or sticky='nsw' mean?

Comment: @Andrew `sticky=` basically tells the widgets to which side of the cell they should stick if the cell becomes larger than the widget, the default is to center the widget in the cell. `N`, `S`, `E` and `W` stand for north, south, east and west, so top, bottom, right and left. `N`, `S`, `E` and `W` are tkinter constants that are defined as `'n'`, `'s'`, `'e'` and `'w'`, so when you want the widget to stick to the top, bottom and left you can use either `sticky=N+S+W` or `sticky='nsw'`. Read more at [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).